# Access Denied to ROAD API

Tags: google-roads-api

I am using a python code to access to speed limits from GPS coordinates of my database, and when I execute the code, the address is provided, but the speed limits not. The error is 'Speed limits are not available for this project. The Road API is enable to my project, but I am not sure of there is some step missing here.

Best regards,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You would have better support for issues like this by contacting the Google Maps Platform Support. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Then moving forward, I suggest that you read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chances of getting help in your future questions. Happy coding!